# How to define a a type consisting of integer values in Alloy

Tags: types, integer, alloy

I try to define a type consisting of integer values in Alloy, but Alloy does not allow the values to be integers. I need to use mathematical operations, and hence, I cannot use strings instead of integers. I need the type so that I can define relations on that too.

I appreciate if you can help me in this regard.
Thanks a lot,
Sincerely,
Fathiyeh

Comment: You can use the build in type int and the functions present in the util/integers library, but except from addition or subtraction on small intervals, you won't be able to do much.

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up to Loïc's comment, integers are usually used to express cardinality of relations, they can be atoms in a relation and Alloy has some support for arithmetic operations. (See "3.7 Cardinality and Integers" of the Alloy book.)